# Why it is printing only 1st value of doubly linked list and than my program is crashing

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create a doubly linked list and then printing its value but the output is showing only first value and then the whole program is crashing.

I can't understand where is the problem in the code .

Input

3

1 2 3

Expected output

1 2 3

current output

1

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class node                                  //declation of node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};
node *makenode(node *head,int val)          //function to create node
{
    node *newnode=new node;
    node *temp;
    newnode->data=val;
    newnode->next=0;
    newnode->prev=0;
    if(head==0) temp=head=newnode;

    else
    {
        temp->next=newnode;
        newnode->prev=temp;
        temp=newnode;
    }
    return head;
}
void display(node *head)                     //display function
{
    system("cls");                          //clearing output screen
    while(head!=0)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<"  ";
        head=head->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    node *head;
    head=0;
    int val;
    int s;                                   //size of list
    cout<<"ENTER THE SIZE OF LIST";
    cin>>s;
    system("cls");
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cout<<"ENTER THE "<<i+1<<" VALUE\n";
        cin>>val;
        head=makenode(head,val);             //calling makenode and putting value
    }
    display(head);                           //printing value
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually linking anything together. This line: `if(head==0) temp=head=newnode;` is the only reason your linked list contains a value at all. The very first value sets head equal to it and when you print head you get that value. In order to properly do a linked list you need a **head** and **tail** pointer. The head points to the first element in the list and the tail points to the last. When you add an element to the end of the list you use tail to find the last element and link to it. It is easiest to make Linked List a class where you can encapsulate head and tail:

```
struct Node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    Node(int data) : data(data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {} // constructor
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    LinkedList() { head = tail = nullptr; }

    // This function adds a node to the end of the linked list
    void add(int data) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == nullptr) { // the list is empty
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else { // the list is not empty
            tail->next = newNode; // point the last element to the new node
            newNode->prev = tail;  // point the new element to the prev
            tail = tail->next;  // point the tail to the new node
        }
    }
};

int main() {

  LinkedList lList;
  lList.add(1);
  lList.add(2);
  // etc...

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
node *makenode(node *head,int val)          //function to create node
{
    node *newnode=new node;
    node *temp;               // #1
    newnode->data=val;
    newnode->next=0;
    newnode->prev=0;
    if(head==0) temp=head=newnode;

    else
    {
        temp->next=newnode;   // #2
```

Between the lines marked `#1` and `#2` above, what exactly is setting the variable `temp` to point to an actual *node* rather than pointing to some arbitrary memory address?

"Nothing", I hear you say? Well, that would be a problem :-)

In more detail, the line:

```
node *temp;
```

will set `temp` to point to some "random" location and, unless your list is currently empty, nothing will *change* that before you attempt to execute:

```
temp->next = newnode;
```

In other words, it will use a very-likely invalid pointer value and crash *if you're lucky.* If you're *unlucky,* it won't crash but will instead exhibit some strange behaviour at some point after that.

---

If you're not worried about the *order* in the list, this could be fixed by just always inserting at the head, with something like:

```
node *makenode(node *head, int val) {
    node *newnode = new node;
    newnode->data = val;
    if (head == 0) { // probably should use nullptr rather than 0.
        newnode->next = 0;
        newnode->prev = 0;
    } else {
        newnode->next = head->next;
        newnode->prev = 0;
    }
    head = newnode;
    return head;
}
```

If you *are* concerned about order, you have to find out where the new node should go, based on the value, such as with:

```
node *makenode(node *head, int val) {
    node *newnode = new node;
    newnode->data = val;

    // Special case for empty list, just make new list.

    if (head == 0) { // probably should use nullptr rather than 0.
        newnode->next = 0;
        newnode->prev = 0;
        head = newnode;
        return head;
    }

    // Special case for insertion before head.

    if (head->data > val) {
        newnode->next = head->next;
        newnode->prev = 0;
        head = newnode;
        return head;
    }

    // Otherwise find node you can insert after, and act on it.

    // Checknode will end up as first node where next is greater than
    // or equal to insertion value, or the last node if it's greater
    // than all current items.

    node *checknode = head;
    while (checknode->next != 0 && (checknode->next->data < val) {
        checknode = checknode->next;
    }

    // Then it's just a matter of adjusting three or four pointers
    // to insert (three if inserting after current last element).

    newnode->next = checknode->next;
    newnode->prev = checknode;
    if (checknode->next != 0) {
        checknode->next->prev = newnode;
    }
    checknode->next = newnode;

    return head;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say @paxdiablo

Comment: @BATMAN_X Your `else` case dereferences `temp` by writing `temp->`, but `temp` was only declared and was never initialised with an address, so it has an undefined value, and so your program has undefined behaviour and in this case crashes. You need to assign some valid memory address of a node to `temp` before you can dereference it.

Comment: @BATMAN_X, I've adjusted that section to hopefully make it clearer.